# How to connect to a PI Webservice, using Python3

Tags: python, kerberos, osisoft

I am trying to connect to a PI Webservice of OSISoft, the official documentation is bad and for the moment I am using as an example https://github.com/SwatiAcharjee/PI-Web-API-Client-Python/blob/master/setup.py.

I installed :

```
pip3 install osipiconnect
```

but when trying to connect to the WS, by means of :

```
client = PIWebApiClient (" https://marc-rras.osisoft.int/piwebapi ", useKerberos = False, username =" marc.adm ", password =" kk ", verifySsl = False)
```

gives me an error of:

```
unexpected keyword argument 'useKerberos'
```

(Supposedly the WS uses Kerberos within the authentication process)

Some idea, or example of how to connect to a PI Webservice, using Python from a machine with GNU Linux??.

regards

Comment: Did you ever get an answer (other than the less than useful regurgitation of links to the even less useful OSI docs?)

Answer (score 2):

OSIsoft's PI Web API has many authentication options, in many companies with a majority of Microsoft computers Kerberos authentication offers a single-sign-on experience.  This is just one way (recommended, and secured) to use the PI Web API.  But there are other ways. See [the OSIsoft Live Library - PI Web API - Authentication options for more details](https://livelibrary.osisoft.com/LiveLibrary/content/en/web-api-v12/GUID-DA5C6E2D-46FE-4961-AF95-642E7B309D9F#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-795C947E-C220-4521-8827-F7840CFE0DEA.xml&docid=GUID-DA5C6E2D-46FE-4961-AF95-642E7B309D9F&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DA5C6E2D-46FE-4961-AF95-642E7B309D9F).  These settings require server-side configuration.

But taking a step back I would probably try to understand what you want to achieve. There are several ways to access and use the data with the PI System.  And PI Web API is just one of them... Are you trying to use the right one? This is a typical case of [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) :).

--

To get a quick start on the multiple ways to use the PI System as a developer have a look here: [OSIsoft PI Developer Technologies](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Products/Developer-Technologies/)

And specifically for PI Web API, you can watch training videos on youtube: [PI Web API online Course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMcG1Hs2Jbcso8Fo7WJses_yVVyV-Zq_R&_ga=2.166179322.51380594.1574502683-969692758.1529656002)

And to get started with the PI System, and understand what it is about, you should look here: [What is the PI System?](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMcG1Hs2JbcvidLkfMecSXH9axNe8bzch)